# Unrecognized selector sent to UIRefreshControl

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am getting this Error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterViewController setRefreshControl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2681e0'
```

How to resolve this issue because in simulator my app is running but on device with the same code my app is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope your simulator is iOS6 Simulator and the device in which you tried to run may have a lower OS version ..right?
.

From [UIRefreshControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference),

> **Availability :** Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

`Refresh control` is new to `iOS6`. So if you want to support `iOS5`, the best thing to do is check if the refresh control class exists (you can use `NSClassFromString` ), and if it doesn't exists either not use it or use an alternative.

Comment: yes my simulator is iOS6 Simulator and i am testing my app on iPad1.

Comment: Yup! Thats it....the solution is well stated in my answer! Either test on a device with iOS6 or Above..it will work fine...what is your app's deployment target required??

Comment: deployment target is iOS 5.0.